# Why do I have to explicitly cast to a constrained type?

Tags: rust

Why doesn't the commented-out `bar` code below compile, even though `foo` and `baz` do?

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::fmt::Display;

// `value` implements `Clone`, so I can call `.clone()`.
fn foo<T: Display + Clone>(value: &T) {
    println!("{}", value.clone());
}

// `value` implements `Any`, so I should be able to call `.downcast_ref`...
// But this doesn't compile!
//
// fn bar<T: Display + Any>(value: &T) {
//     println!("{}", value.downcast_ref::<i32>());
// }

// For some reason I have to do an explicit cast to `&Any`...
fn baz<T: Display + Any>(value: &T) {
    let value = value as &Any;
    println!("{}", value.downcast_ref::<i32>().unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    foo(&7);
    // bar(&8);
    baz(&9);
}
```

Trying to compile `bar` yields the following compiler error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast_ref` found for type `&T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:30
   |
13 |         println!("{}", value.downcast_ref::<i32>());
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I already spelled out the constraint that `value` must implement `Any` so why do I have to do an explicit cast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because [`downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref) is not part of the trait itself. If we look at the trait's definition [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html):

```
pub trait Any: 'static {
    fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId;
}
```

we can see that `downcast_ref` is not there. Only methods defined as members of a trait are made available on types that implements that trait.

Rather, `downcast_ref` is in an `impl Any + 'static` block<sup>1</sup>. Since the method takes `&self`, it means the method is only available on values of type `&(Any + 'static)` (`&Any` with no lifetime specified is equivalent to `&(Any + 'static)`). `&Any` and `&T` (where `T` is a type parameter) are not the same type; `&Any` is a trait object (which is a fat pointer), while `&T` is just a normal reference (which is a thin pointer).

---

<sup>1</sup> It's also defined in an `impl Any + 'static + Send` block, so the method is also available on values of type `&(Any + 'static + Send)`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `downcast_ref()` **can't** be part of the trait: it is generic and generic methods on traits make the trait *not object safe*. This means that we couldn't create trait objects of `Any` if `downcast_ref()` were part of the trait. And that would pretty much destroy the whole purpose of `Any` ;-)